# Modularizing classpaths in ant scripts (e.g. via refid)

Tags: java, ant, build

Since my ant file is quite complex, I want to modularize my classpath-elements.

Currently, I use `refid` in the following way:

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
  <pathelement path="foo"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</path>

<path id="test.classpath">
  <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
  <pathelement path="bar"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</path>

<!-- ... -->

    <javac>
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>

    <junit>
        <!-- ... -->
        <classpath>
             <path refid="test.classpath"/>
             <path path="bazz"/>
        </classpath>
    </junit>

<!-- ... -->
```

Is this a sensible approach? Or is there a better one?

Is it ok to use a path-id (`compile.classpath`) for a classpath-refid (in `<javac>`)? (It currently works, but `refid` does require the elements to be of the same type. Since `path` and `classpath` are both path-like structures, are they of the same type?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I successfully used this approach at a previous job and it was really the only way I could keep everything sane.

I eventually took things a step further an put all my third-party library definitions in a separate `ext-libs.xml` file since several of them were multi-jar libraries and making sure I had all of them contained in my final war files was getting to be a giant hassle.  That way, in my main `build.xml` (and others) I could refer to, say, `lib.jaxb` and not have to worry that I'd updated the version numbers in the files names everywhere.

You've already figured out the trick of extending your compile classpath to make your test classpath, so you're on the right track.

In short, press on.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my approach (+1). Since I do not want to include all third-party libraries everywhere, I made several groupings in path-elements, like compile.classpath and test.classpath, which I can then combine and extend. It works, I just wasn't sure whether there is some standard-solution for this that I've missed.